# Why cant I use Request.ServerVariables["ALL_HTTP"] in the C# code file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I can use  `Request.ServerVariables["ALL_HTTP"]` in the .Aspx file between % tags, 
i.e., `<%=Request.ServerVariables["ALL_HTTP"]%>`
But the .cs file will not recognize the namespace. What gives? I need to get those vars into an array in my code file.

Comment: What gives? Probably gives an error. What might that be?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead, "The name 'Request' does not exist in the current context", i.e., "will not recognize the namespace."

Comment: Have you tried `HttpContext.Current.Request`?

Comment: Simon's answer should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using System.Collections.Specialized;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        NameValueCollection coll;
        coll = Request.ServerVariables;
        // Get names of all keys into a string array. 
        String[] arr1 = coll.AllKeys;
        for (int loop1 = 0; loop1 < arr1.Length; loop1++)
        {
            Response.Write("Key: " + arr1[loop1] + "<br>");
            String[] arr2 = coll.GetValues(arr1[loop1]);
            for (int loop2 = 0; loop2 < arr2.Length; loop2++)
            {
                Response.Write("Value " + loop2 + ": " + Server.HtmlEncode(arr2[loop2]) + "<br>");
            }
        }


    }
}
```